# Уведомления для клиента сайта на WordPress

Tags: android, wordpress

Установил на сайт плагин Push Notifications for WordPress (Lite), настроил вроде бы. Получил server key в firebase ввел в настройках плагина. поставил галочки

Send push notifications to Android devices

Use the Notification message instead of the Data message

Send push notifications

Send Push Notifications for Записи

Подскажите как дальше двигаться? Есть ли какая-то инструкция или пример. После всех этих настроек добавил на сайт запись, но уведомление не пришло. Я так понимаю еще какие-то шаги нужно выполнить

Вот что у меня сейчас есть

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.udeveloper.clientudeveloper">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Класс MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

Класс MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]


    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .build();
        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }


    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                        .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Класс MyJobService

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyJobService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Performing long running task in scheduled job");
        // TODO(developer): add long running task here.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну а в приложении вы настроили приём пушей? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Нет, а есть на русском какой-то пример что куда нужно добавлять в приложении? :)

Comment: Например что за ресурс такой default_notification_channel_id в документации по данной вами ссылке смотрю пример. Там такой идентификатор нужен, но я не пойму откуда его взять

Comment: Через консоль FireBase попробовал отправить сообщение на устройство где установлено приложение оно пришло. А вот на сайте когда запись добавляется что-то не приходит сообщение